# Scala collection select elements until first one meet a requirement

Tags: scala

For example I have following Scala list, I want get a sublist until there is a requirement can be met.

```
val list = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,5,4,1,2,5)
```

The requirement is the number is 5, so I want the result as:

```
Seq(1,2,3,4)
```

Currently I use Scala collection's `indexWhere` and `splitAt` to return:

```
list.splitAt(list.indexWhere(x => x == 5))

(Seq(1,2,3,4), Seq(5,5,4,1,2,5))
```

I am not sure there are more better ways to achieve the same with better Scala collection's method I didn't realise?

Comment: I'm not trying to be funny, but did you try reading the documentation? The first thing I do when I think there might be a standard method for something is to scan the list of (in this case) Seq methods, and that would have quickly led you to `span` and `takeWhile` (`takeWhile`'s name being particularly suggestive in this case). See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@takeWhile(p:A=>Boolean):Repr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `span` like this,

```
val (l,r) = list.span(_ != 5)
```

which delivers

```
l: List(1, 2, 3, 4)
r: List(5, 5, 4, 1, 2, 5)
```

Alternatively, you can write

```
val l = list.span(_ != 5)._1
```

to access only the first element of the resulting tuple.

This bisects the list at the first element that does not hold the condition.

Comment: Although elm's answer is valid, I believe that `List#takeWhile` by Ende should be the accepted answer due to simplicity. Since the OP wants only the `l` in elm's, I'd argue that Ende's submitted answer is simpler.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, on the contrary,the OP's sample output shows both the list before the 5, and the remainder of the list.

Comment: On the contrary to your contrariness :), the OP said `The requirement is the number is 5, so I want the result as:

'Seq(1,2,3,4)'`

Comment: "Oh, cool. takeWhile and dropWhile" suggests otherwise. But we're both attempting mindreading, maybe the OP will drop by to let us know :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `takeWhile`:

```
scala> val list = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,5,4,1,2,5)
list: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 1, 2, 5)

scala> list.takeWhile(_ != 5)
res30: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```